# How do I transform a data generation specification in R into a BUGS/JAGS specification

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, bugs, jags

I am at a loss about what the BUGS/JAGS specification of the following should look like.  The background is that one person has four measurements taken by four different instruments.  Each instrument is expected to have a different associated error.  The R code for generating simulated data (not very elegant) is:

```
n <- 63                    # Number of patients

## (Hyper)parameters
var_a <- 2                  # Variance around population mean
mu_a <- 80                  # population mean
mu_m <- c(0, -5, 1, -6)     # Mean diff for each measurement instrument from the population mean
var_m <- c(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5)  # Variance of each measurement instrument
m_i <- 0                    # Individual measurement error (mean)
m_e <- 1                    # Individual measurement error (variance)

# Counter to keep track of total number of measurements taken
measures.taken <- 0


## Generate the data
for (i in 1:n){                                                       # loop around the number of patients
  a <- mu_a + rnorm(1, 0, sqrt(var_a))                                # Random intercept
  for (j in 1:length(mu_m)){                                          # Loop to generate 4 measures for each patient
    measures.taken <- measures.taken + 1                              # Just keeping track of the number of measurements in total
    individual.error <- rnorm(1, m_i, sqrt(m_e))   
    bp <- rnorm(1, mu_m[j], sqrt(var_m[j])) + a + individual.error   # This sets up the random variability for the measures
    print(c(bp, i, j))                                               # Print data as generated to the standard output
  } 
}
```

Any insights gratefully accepted.

Comment: I should add that I am principally interested in estimating the separate variance associated with each measurement instrument.

Answer (score 2):

It should be somewhere along this line:

The first part is the model for the measurements, tau_bp refers to the individual errors here:

```
for (i in 1:n){
bp[i]~dnorm(lambda[j],tau_bp)
```

}

The second part is to model the different mean and standard deviation of the different treatments:

```
 for (j in 1:4){
    lambda[j]~dnorm(mu[j],tau[j])
...    
}
```

Then you proceed to write down the models for each different type of measurements and the hyperparameters.

From my experience, it's much easier if you write down your final model on a piece of paper, then tackle each part of it separately. Hope this can get you started!